# Mouse exited on inner component hover

Tags: java, swing

I have created a JFrame with a JPanel containing different components, and for example I want the JPanel to have a visible border and a visible image when the mouse is inside the bounds of the JPanel. My problem is that as soon as the mouse hovers over an "interactable" component inside the JPanel it will register as the mouse exited the JPanel. I'd like it to draw these things as long as it's inside the bounds of the JPanel, and when the mouse exits the JPanel's bounds the border and image "dissappear". Is there any way to achieve this?

Here's a little demo:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    static class TestFrame extends JFrame{
        JPanel panel;
        JButton hoverButton;
        JButton appearingButton;
        public TestFrame() {
            super();
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.red);
            hoverButton = new JButton("Hover me!");
            appearingButton = new JButton("I appeared!");
            appearingButton.setVisible(false);
            panel.add(hoverButton);
            panel.add(appearingButton);
            panel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("Entered!");
                    appearingButton.setVisible(true);
                }
                public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("Exited!");
                    appearingButton.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            add(panel);
            setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setVisible(true);
        }

    }

}
```

While having the mouse inside the JPanel (covering the full JFrame) the second button will appear. Hovering over the first button will however make the second button dissappear. I'd like the second button to show as long as you are inside the bounds of the JPanel.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a lot more difficult then it sounds.  You need to be able to monitor all mouse events for the child components of your container.  Unfortunately, you either get a all-or-nothing solutions.  That is, you either get the problem you have right now, where the `MouseListener` stops reporting mouse events once another component starts capturing them (this is how the mouse listener API works) or you can see ALL the mouse events that the system is processing.

This leaves you with the need to provide some kind of filtering process, so you can filter out those events that you are not interested in, for example...

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source instanceof JComponent) {
                JComponent comp = (JComponent) source;
                if (SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(parent, comp)) {
                    // The mouse is in the house...
                }
            }
        }
    }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
```

*(parent is you main container)*

This basically attaches a `AWTEventListener` into the main event processing framework, which will tell you ALL the events of a particular type which are been processed.  You then need to check to see if the event in question actually occurred within your context of interest (yourself or one of it's children) before taking appropriate action...

## Java 10 (~ 8+?)/2018

There seems to have been some changes to the way the event mechanisms work since I wrote the original answer (and I also made some minor mistakes )

In order for a the `AWTListener` to generate events, all "interested" components need to register for mouse events

I did a very basic test, creating a plain old `JPanel` (and a button) and added them to the parent container and used...

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {});
panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {});
add(panel);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent) source;
            System.out.println(comp);
            if (SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(comp, TestPane.this)) {
                // The mouse is in the house...
                System.out.println("Mouse in the house");
            }
        }
    }
}, AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

This generated events for both the button and the panel

Comment: Can you please include that you have to either enable mouse events for or add a mouse listener to `parent`. Otherwise no mouse events will be fired, see also the [MouseEvent documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html).

Comment: @Marcono1234 This approach is listening directly to the event dispatching queue - there is no need to "register" any other interest, as you are directly at the coal face - after this listener is called, the events will be dispatched to components who have previous registered interest in events - it's kind of the point

Comment: Are you sure? When I implemented it (and had no regular `MouseListener`s for `parent`) neither MOUSE_EXITED nor MOUSE_ENTERED events were fired for it.
I assume for the other mouse event types it does not matter since they are not directly component related.

Comment: And I think you should use `AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK` as event mask. `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED` appears to be no event mask and causes the listener to be notified for all kind of events, including ComponentEvent, WindowEvent, ...

Comment: @Marcono1234 The example is using `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED` mask

Comment: @Marcono1234 Since this was done in 2015 - it's likely that  API has changed. While this is definitely a global listener, it does seem that if you want the source to be addressed to the component, then yes, you do need to register for interest directly, however, you could just find the component at the specified point manually

Comment: the problem is that `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED` appears to be no event mask but an event id, which is likely why it matches unrelated event types as described above.

Comment: And even when listening for mouse motion (`AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK`) it appears you have to register a mouse motion listener, otherwise no event will be fired.

Comment: @Marcono1234 "Welcome to the future"

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot, this helped me catch difficult to tackle problems with mouseExit in a `JTable`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add a mouse listener to every child component in the JPanel.

Using your code, here's one way:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HoverTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HoverTest hoverTest = new HoverTest();
                hoverTest.new TestFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6304847277329579360L;

        JPanel panel;

        JButton hoverButton;
        JButton appearingButton;

        public TestFrame() {
            super();
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.red);

            hoverButton = new JButton("Hover me!");

            appearingButton = new JButton("I appeared!");
            appearingButton.setVisible(false);

            ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(appearingButton);

            panel.add(hoverButton);
            panel.add(appearingButton);
            panel.addMouseListener(listener);

            hoverButton.addMouseListener(listener);
            appearingButton.addMouseListener(listener);

            add(panel);

            setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    private class ButtonListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private JButton appearingButton;

        public ButtonListener(JButton appearingButton) {
            this.appearingButton = appearingButton;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Entered!");
            appearingButton.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Exited!");
            appearingButton.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI- This could produce memory leaks, if child components are removed, the MouseListener will maintain a strong reference to the components preventing it from be garbage collected

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a lot easier than you think:

```
panel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
          System.out.println("Entered!");
          appearingButton.setVisible(true);
      }
      public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
           if( ! panel.contains( evt.getPoint() ) ){
                System.out.println("Exited!");
                appearingButton.setVisible(false);
           }
      }
});
```

The ***if*** statement will filter out all ***mouseExited*** events that occur while the mouse is still within the panel.

One consequence is that you will end up receiving multiple ***mouseEntered*** events without a ***mouseExited*** between them, but any issues caused by this can be easily avoided.

Comment: This will sadly not work if there is no gap between the parent and the child.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar situation with a `JTable` when the cell was being edited.

The `JTable` had a mouse listener, which was tracking the mouse location, however as soon as a cell started to be edited, the table was not receiving a `mouseExited` / `MOUSE_EXITED` event. At first I chose to check if the pointer was within the table bounds, e.g.

```java
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    var lastestLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(location, component);

    if (table.contains(latestLocation)) return; // bail out

    // do something with the table row
}
```

When *mouse exit* event were received it was working, but I discovered that sometimes when the pointer was moving a bit differently, usually too fast, then *mouse exit* event were not fired, **even when the pointer actually moved out of the `JTable`**.

And by trying [*MadProgrammer*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729833/48136), the problem went away. Here's a slight modification, that performs the check using the bounds, instead of traversing the component tree. Also I wanted to emit event related to the table, not the actual source.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(awtEvent -> {
    var source = awtEvent.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JComponent) {
        var comp = (JComponent) source;
        // The actual received event may come from a different component than the table
        var tableMouseEvent = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(
                comp,
                (MouseEvent) awtEvent,
                interactiveTable
        );
        if (interactiveTable.contains(tableMouseEvent.getPoint())) {
            // The mouse is in the house...
            listeners.forEach(l -> l.mouseMoveWithin(tableMouseEvent));
        } else {
            // Mouse is outside
            listeners.forEach(l -> l.mouseOut(tableMouseEvent));
        }
    }
}, AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

---

11.0.17+8-LTS
bsd-aarch64 macOs 13.1